# Не компилируется Kotlin-проект

Tags: kotlin, gradle, компилятор

Не компилируется Kotlin проект.
Ошибка:
`org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated`
Полная ошибка:

```
    e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 1
    CHECKCAST java/lang/Number
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Number.intValue ()I
   L1
    LINENUMBER 33 L1
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    ARETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 0
    LOCALVARIABLE receiver Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 1
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 2

File is unknown
The root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.endVisit(FunctionCodegen.java:936)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:493)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:261)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PropertyReferenceCodegen.generateAccessors(PropertyReferenceCodegen.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PropertyReferenceCodegen.generateBody(PropertyReferenceCodegen.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generatePropertyReference(ExpressionCodegen.java:3221)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallableReferenceExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:3181)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallableReferenceExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallableReferenceExpression.accept(KtCallableReferenceExpression.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:304)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genLazy(ExpressionCodegen.java:404)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genEqualsForExpressionsPreferIeee754Arithmetic(ExpressionCodegen.java:3754)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateEquals(ExpressionCodegen.java:3521)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateExpressionMatch(ExpressionCodegen.java:4938)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateWhenCondition(ExpressionCodegen.java:5128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.lambda$generateWhenExpression$36(ExpressionCodegen.java:5060)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.lambda$visitReturnExpression$11(ExpressionCodegen.java:1642)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValueWithLeaveTask.putSelector(StackValue.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1731)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:654)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:479)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:261)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.gen(FunctionCodegen.java:148)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genSimpleMember(MemberCodegen.java:197)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassBodyCodegen.java:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:134)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:634)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:194)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node:
get (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;:
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 1
    CHECKCAST java/lang/Number
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Number.intValue ()I
   L1
    LINENUMBER 33 L1
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    ARETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 0
    LOCALVARIABLE receiver Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 1
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 2

File is unknown
The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.MethodVerifier.transform(MethodVerifier.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.endVisit(FunctionCodegen.java:929)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: AFTER mandatory stack transformations: incorrect bytecode
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.MethodVerifier.transform(MethodVerifier.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.CompositeMethodTransformer.transform(CompositeMethodTransformer.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.OptimizationMethodVisitor.performTransformations(OptimizationMethodVisitor.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:70)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction 6: Argument 1: expected R, but found I
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.MethodTransformer.runAnalyzer(MethodTransformer.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.MethodTransformer.analyze(MethodTransformer.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.MethodVerifier.transform(MethodVerifier.kt:26)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction 6: Argument 1: expected R, but found I
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:291)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.optimization.transformer.MethodTransformer.runAnalyzer(MethodTransformer.java:31)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Argument 1: expected R, but found I
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicVerifier.naryOperation(BasicVerifier.java:401)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicVerifier.naryOperation(BasicVerifier.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.execute(Frame.java:613)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:187)
    ... 90 more


e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generate
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
}

group = "ru.cororo.lib"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/")
        content {
            includeGroup("org.bukkit")
            includeGroup("org.spigotmc")
        }
    }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
        name = "bungeecord-repo"
    }
    maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    compileOnly("net.md-5:bungeecord-chat:1.12-SNAPSHOT")
    compileOnly("org.bukkit:bukkit:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT") // The Bukkit API with no shadowing.
    compileOnly("org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    compileOnly("com.github.MilkBowl:VaultAPI:1.7")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks {
    jar {
        doFirst {
            from({
                configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Где компилирую - IntelliJ IDEA, Gradle, Kotlin v1.3.72 (так же пробовал на 1.3.71, 1.3.70, 1.4-M2)

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Покажите этот класс и строку 92 TransformationMethodVisitor

Comment: КАК? это компонент компилятора IntelliJ IDEA @SergeiBuvaka

Comment: Это похоже на ваш случай: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38657

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja т.е. это не мои проблемы?

Comment: Проект-то ваш :) Либо перепишите иначе проблемный кусок кода, либо ждите фикс от JetBrains.